# How to trace function created in another function in R?

Tags: r, function, trace

I am trying to trace function `f1` which is created in
another function `h()`. However, the following shows that I am not able
to trace it even I specify "where". Does anybody know how to solve this
problem?

```
R> g=function() {
+   x=1
+   f=function() {
+     y=x+1
+     y+2
+   }
+ }
R>
R> h=function() {
+ f1=g()
+ f1()
+ }
R> trace(h, browser)
[1] "h"
R> h()
Tracing h() on entry
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> n
debug: {
    f1 = g()
    f1()
}
Browse[2]> n
debug at #2: f1 = g()
Browse[2]> n
debug at #3: f1()
Browse[2]> trace(f1, browser, where=environment(f1))
Tracing function "f1" in package "base"
[1] "f1"
```

Comment: what does `environment(f1)` return?  what does `trace(g,[something])` return at the same point in the browser?